# IIS Disable caching of WCF Automatic HTTP Service Help Page?

Tags: wcf, iis

It seems like IIS is caching the output of the WCF Automatic HTTP Service Help Page, even though I have Output Caching completely turned off.

The problem shows up when I try to access the page from 2 different URLS  (say localhost for debugging and our external facing URL). Clicking through the help page through one server will cache the result (with the URL listed at the top) for the other calls from the other URL, at which point the incorrect URL (say localhost) will be shown for access from external URLs. Which will no doubt confuse users of our external facing endpoints.

I'm using IIS 7. I've tried turning off Output Caching (both via web.config and via IIS Site settings). I've tried restarting (browser, IIS, site). I've tried clearing the cache (in browser). But I still can't fix the problem.